# Synchronize single file with WinScp

Tags: script, sync, winscp

I am trying to synchronize a single file with WinScp. But it is downloading that file every time the script runs. But I want it to download that file only when there is any update in the remote file.

Here are the commands I am using in my script

```
option include /home/username/test.csv
synchronize local c:\test /home/username -mirror
```

The `username` contains more than just `test.csv` but I only wants to synchronize `test.csv`. The script above downloads only `test.csv`, this is ok, But it downloads every time I run the script instead of downloading only when if there is any update in the remote file.

I tried to synchronize whole directory that is working perfectly fine but I needs it to work with the single file.

any idea?

Comment: -mirror don't needed here

Comment: option include test.csv

Comment: When you say that the whole directory sync works fine, do you mean that test.csv is only synced when it is modified?

Comment: The `option include` cannot affect, if the file is synced or not when changed. So I do not believe that full dir sync works correctly, while single file dir does not.